# Export to Font Awesome - Simple dashed Line - Affinity Design 2.3

Tags: export, affinity-designer

I can't seem to figure out the right settings... Font Awesome keeps telling me my "stroke" needs to be expanded yet I already did that.  There is not a stroke in my file.  I am not privy to svg and just trying to get these working so I can make my icons for my other application.

Used a path tool, created a dashed line, expanded the stroke and then exported to svg.  What am I missing?

The object is to centralize most of these little icons required in font-awesome... Can't believe they don't have a telco set.  If I knew how to export these I would be making quite a few.  From RG6 connectors to RJ45.  Lots of awesome shit I could put up there for use in wiring industries.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots so we can perhaps help?

I've not used Font Awesome in forever - but I do use Affinity Designer to create SVGs pretty frequently - post images and maybe we can help!